# Got caught faking hospital papers

Tags: health, personal-misconduct

I am fourth year mathematics students. I couldn't attend two of my final exams due to my depression, the situation made me feel worse so and I felt like it was over if I failed. I cannot afford to pay for an extra year and getting an F will cause an iireversible damage to my GPA. Knwoing they won't accept depression as a reason I faked a hospital paper of my sister being covid positive and submitted it to the dean telling him my reason for not attending was that I contacted someone with covid. However, they found out the report was fake. They told me they won't take legal actions and let it slide this time. But at the momement I was so scared and I started insisting that my sister doesn't have a reason to lie or give a fake report. They told me they called the hospital and the file is shown to be edited but I know both of these things can't be true. Am I shooting myself at the foot?

Comment: I think you know the answer to the (rhetorical?) question as it is currently stated. Stop lying, and be grateful that the university let it slide. If you do the best you can from now on and decide not to lie again you should be fine, both in a career inside our outside of academia. But I do not understand what your question is, please clarify.

Comment: It's not the answer to your question. But, do you have a person you trust that you can discuss these things with? This is clearly a deeply concerning thing. You should have somebody to find the best answers with.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are shooting yourself in the foot.

I am not sure why you would assume that they would not accept your depression as a valid reason, but even if so, faking doctor notes is not the way to go. You could have reached out to the course instructor or the department advisor for help and asked for accommodation.

Anyway, now is the time to try to find a way to deal with the consequences of your actions.